# XML add content of external element inside CDATA

Tags: xml

I have an XML file that is passed to a XML parser, I need to load content from external resource like the following:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE foo [<!ELEMENT foo ANY >
<!ENTITY data SYSTEM "file:///d:/data.txt" >]>
<component id="200">
  <![CDATA[&data;]]>
</component>
```

I want the data to be written inside the CDATA tag, however, this just introduces `<![CDATA[&data;]]>` and the external resource data is never fetched because of `CDATA` tag considered as comment I guess.

The data must be inside CDATA tag to be accepted.
How can this be achieved?

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have to read/parse the XML document and how you read the data from the `<component>` tag. Also add the language tag of the programming language you are using.

Comment: Be careful about expanding the entities because of an attack named [Billion laughs attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs_attack).

Comment: I don't have control over the XML paraser, it's an API that takes the XML from me and the data file is located somewhere in the server that I can upload files to.

Comment: By definition, everything inside a `<![CDATA[...]]>` doesn't get "parsed". So when you write `<![CDATA[&data;]]>` you have the string value `"&data;"`. But since you are providing the XML you can insert the data before sending it to the API.

Comment: I can't, the data is located on the API server and only the API server can access it. It's uploaded there by various users. Is there a way to wrap something inside a CDATA tag using XML?

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements seem self-contradictory. The whole point of `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` is that everything within the brackets (except for `]]>`) is treated as regular character data, not as markup. If you want to use entity references like `&data;` that's fine, but putting them in a CDATA section is an explicit instruction to the XML parser to ignore them.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2784200/5832619) appears to contradict this